# Align 4 images in a list to the center of a Page with the wrapper

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am really new to HTML and working on a project which needs to be completed today. Here I want 4 images aligned horizontally at the center of the the page with white color backround.

```
         <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome to Food Court</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

    <div class="navigation" >

            <ul>
                <li>
<a href="myfile.htm"><img src="images/fb.png" alt="Smiley face" height="150px"width="150px"></a>

        </li>


                <li>
                <a href="myfile.htm">   <img src="images/Parking.png" alt="Smiley face" height="150px"width="150px"> </a>
                </li>


                <li>
                <a href="myfile.htm"><img src="images/signage.png" alt="Smiley face" height="150px"width="150px"></a>
                </li>
        <li>
        <a href="myfile.htm"><img src="images/ticketing.png" alt="Smiley face" height="150px"width="150px"></a>
                </li>



</ul>   

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html {
    background: url('images/bg.png');
    font-size: 10pt;
}
label {
    display: block;
    color: #999;
margin-bottom:2px;
margin-top:10px;
}

.navigation ul {
    margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;

}
.navigation li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

.navigation ul li a { text-decoration: none;


padding: .2em 1em;


 }

 #wrapper{

 background:white;

 width:900px;
 height:300px;
 top:50%;
     left:50%;
     margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;
     position:absolute;


 }

 .navigation{


     position:absolute;
     width:750px;
     height:200px;
     z-index:15;
     top:50%;
     left:50%;
     margin:-100px 0px 100px -150px;

}
```

The issue I am facing here is that page is not aligning exactly to the center of the page. Also I had to use the same property to the wrapper that I`ve used to the #navigation if I need white background. But somewhere things messing up that I am not really getting the expected output as you can see from the fiddle below.

The images are not aligning from the start of the Wrapper div but leaving out space..

I need the list with 4 images exactly placed at the center of the page with white the backround  ..

It would be of great help if someone can guide me whats actually going in here..

Since I ran out of option I had no option but ask for help here.Thanks in advance.!

Please find the fiddle link below..

http://jsfiddle.net/0yvtt1ch/

Comment: Your html structure is messed up. You have an `a` tag outside the `li`, you have a oppened `li` tag without a closing one, you should fix first those.

Comment: Apologies. have just done that and updated the code. Still, somehow 1st image is leaving out some space before starts aligning inside the wrapper..

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pauldic/patd812r/) you can you the absolute-center class to align the child content to the center. Also notice that you have some errors in you html-ui syntax which I fixed in the example

```
.absolute-center{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, paullo! I could see that both the divs are not aligned to the center of the page! Is there anyway to achieve that??

Comment: If you want them aligned to the center of the page I have modified the JSFiddle to here http://jsfiddle.net/Pauldic/patd812r/1/. Let me know if it meets your need

Comment: Thanks a lot,paullo. one last query.. Background color for the wrapper is not perfectly spreading out. If I give width=900px.. I need that 900px spread across equally on the both the sides.. please let me know how should I handle that.. Thanks again for all ur help!!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Background color for the wrapper is not perfectly spreading out". That example a posted http://jsfiddle.net/Pauldic/patd812r/1 is perfectly aligned both horizonal and vertiacl. Note that the #wrapper is the RED container that houses the div.navigation (white background) which contains the ui>li. If you can clarify your point, I will be glad to assist

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I think I just discovered your point now, #wrapper left aligned? I have fixed it with margin: auto; here is the update http://jsfiddle.net/Pauldic/patd812r/2/. Let me know if we are in sync now

Answer (score 0):

For aligning them horizontally as well you can do this with the wrapper. Credit for most of it goes to Paullo.

```
#wrapper{ 
     background:red;

     width:900px;
     height:300px;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     bottom:0;
     right:0;
     margin:auto;
     position:absolute;     
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qe3z397r/

Comment: You could have used a comment anyways!

Comment: I need 50 rep to comment or I would have.

Comment: Oops, I see., its okay. I think you did what you can. I am sorry for that